# Visual Studio Code ASP.NET Edit and Continue

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does Edit and Continue currently work for ASP.NET debugging in Visual Studio Code, or is it a planned feature of Visual Studio Code at some point?

Comment: What kind/version of ASP.Net?

Comment: Answered here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387985/edit-and-continue-in-asp-net-web-projects>