# Edit and Continue options per Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, edit-and-continue

I'm working simultaneously on 2 projects, one .Net WINFORMS and the other ASP.NET website.

Due to some quirks I've yet to figure out, on ASP website projects to enable Edit and Continue, you actually have to deselect Edit and Continue in the Options, Debugging menu.

This causes frustration when I switch back to the Winforms project, when I can no longer natively edit and continue because its been deselected.

1. Is there a way to enable edit and continue in ASP Website with the Edit and Continue option remaining ticked?

or

2. Is there a setting to save debugging options specific to a solution, and not global?

Comment: AFAIK, Edit and Continue is not supported in Web Site projects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387985/edit-and-continue-in-asp-net-web-projects, are you using ASP.NET web application not websites and how did you enable Edit and Continue on ASP website projects? Besides, I am afraid there is no such setting to save debugging options specific to a solution, and not global.

Comment: @Brendan Gooden, Are your two projects in the same solution? Do you use the latest VS2017 15.8.1? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue-visual-csharp?view=vs-2017, it doesn't support certain project types in default.

Comment: Sorry I didnt make it clear, they are 2 separate solutions.

Comment: @Brendan Gooden, Not get your response for about one week, but like my previous answer, it really doesn't have this feature like you expect, but you could also submit a feature request to the product team here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio. The Visual Studio product team is listening to user voice. You can send your idea there and people can vote.  Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

Edit and Continue will be set for all solutions, I mean that if you disable it for one solution, it still was disabled in default if you create a new solution using the same VS again. It has no this feature just for only one solution.

Of course, if IntelliTrace is enabled and you collect both IntelliTrace events and call information, Edit and Continue is disabled. It means that it doesn't work even if you enable it under TOOLS->Options->Debugging.

[image]